# Create AWS's launch configuration for Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am working for the `AWS's Autoscaling`.

One thing I am confused is new launched instances from `Autoscaling` is based on the AMI of that instance.

I have one instance that is created from an AMI of a snapshot of one volume.

My concern is that if new instances are launched based on that AMI, those new updates in the instance will not be included in the new launched instances using that AMI. Because only instance has new updates and that AMI is fixed and never update.

Is that consideration valid?
If that is true, how to make sure newly launched instance by Autoscaling has all what the `scale in instance` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a **point-in-time snapshot** of an Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) Volume.

Therefore, any Amazon EC2 instance launched by Auto Scaling will contain an EBS Volume that **exactly matches** the contents of the AMI as at the time that the AMI was created.

This is fully intentional and working as expected. The intention is that you can create an AMI that contains all the software and configuration that is necessary for the EC2 instances being launched by Auto Scaling. Each instance will have its **own copy of the AMI** as its boot disk.

If your intention is to replicate/share data between multiple EC2 instances, then you should store your data somewhere that all instances can access, such as:

- A database
- An Amazon S3 bucket
- Amazon Elastic File System (EFS) (shared storage amongst multiple instances)
- A disk share between the instances (configured in the operating system)

Comment: I'd add:a file sharing server, for app code repository is good too :) Configure the instance to connect to whatever storage you choose at boot/configuration time.

Comment: Is it possible to update new AMI at launch configuration? I mean, is launch configuration editable?

Comment: Yeah now I know how to reflect changes at instance. Create a new AMI of that updated instance. Using that new AMI, create a new launch configuration. Then update new launch configuration to AutoScaling. Then, autoscaling will launch upto date instances.